# <li> in a <ul> sometimes do not remove list-style graphics (mainly noticed in Bootstrap drop-down-menus)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Every now and then my `list items` will have their 'bulletpoints' visible. This happens on different pages at different times. I do not have any custom CSS overlaying my bootstrap `<li>`'s.

Are there any measures I can put in place to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below:

```
 li {
  list-style: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```